# Why TextRecognize reads data organized in grid by column and not by row?

Tags: ocr

Why `TextRecognize` reads the text by column and not by line in the following scenarios?

The lines are perfect, the font is perfect, image quality is perfect so I do not understand why it does not read it normally by line.

Also notice that it reads `66` as `55`, in fact every `6` it read as `5`.
Also in the second example it reads `UJ` as `U]` or `XB` as `xB` or `QC` as `Qc`.

The conditions can not be more perfect so why it fails in such ideal situation?

Input:

```
im=ImagePad[Rasterize[Grid[Partition[ToString[#[[1]]]~StringJoin~ToString[#[[2]]]&/@Partition[RandomInteger[9,105],2],7,7,{1,1},{}]],ImageSize->300],10,White]
TextRecognize[im,"Line"]
```

Output:

[image: grid1]

```
{"58", "95", "08", "55", "25", "02", "49", "84", "13", "04", "18", \
"74", "78", "19", "25", "95", "95", "35", "59", "00", "18", "94", \
"49", "10", "20", "32", "82", "88", "32", "49", "25", "98", "70", \
"87", "59", "28", "27", "84", "10", "41", "32", "27", "55", "25", \
"23", "57", "00", "55", "83", "42", "80", "97"}
```

Input:

```
im=ImagePad[Rasterize[Grid[Partition[ToString[#[[1]]]~StringJoin~ToString[#[[2]]]&/@Partition[CharacterRange["A","Z"][[1+RandomInteger[25,105]]],2],7,7,{1,1},{}]],ImageSize->300],10,White]
TextRecognize[im,"Line"]
```

Output:

[image]

```
{"BF", "LS", "IZ", "IX", "ZP", "NO", "ME", "QL", "LF", "YL", "SO", \
"LE", "FV", "CS", "EX", "CT", "FY", "BX", "KL", "EU", "KS", "WR", \
"LT", "PA", "CX", "IK", "PI", "GV", "MN", "OT", "FK", "xB", "DY", \
"Qc", "DN", "UL", "HB", "wz", "FY", "MH", "U]", "PK", "XL", "YT", \
"PQ", "DM", "IP", "CS", "SM", "Z]", "WV", "KF"}
```

Comment: Pretty weird! Using `TextRecognize[im, "Line", RecognitionPrior -> "SparseText"]` - it seems to work row-by-row instead but the results are poor.